# Calculating JFET stats for a constant current source

Tags: current, constant-current, jfet, lm317, calculation

I need to find a constant current source for a variable LM317 current regulator (schematic below), and I would like to know which JFETs to use. Can somebody let me know how much current I need and which specs to use including:

- Drain to Source voltage (Vdss)
- Current Drain (Idss)

Also, a side question: How necessary is the -10V in the schematic? Can I get away just using ground and having my regulator only go down to 1.25V?

[image: JFET current source and LM317]

(Diagram from [ON-Semi LM317 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm317-d.pdf) , "Figure 22. ‘Laboratory’ Power Supply with Adjustable Current Limit and Output Voltage")

Comment: Please _inline_ your schematic.

Comment: If that diagram is from another source, could you please provide a reference in line with site guidelines?  Could you also say a bit more about what you are trying to achieve with your ciruit?

Comment: Klumpy, The elephant in the room is that JFETs are very, very poorly specified devices. (What few still exist.) The 2N3822 gives Idss as anything from 2 mA to 10 mA in the case where Vds=15 V. But what is the Idss range when Vds=4 V? Not specified. If you want 0 A out at 0 V out then D1 and D2 need to drop 1.25 V. The 1N4001 is also terribly specified. So there's no real idea what their drops might be with anything from 2 mA to 10 mA (assuming Vds=15V) through them, either. But the drain needs to be -1.25 or less. So the -10 V is probably fine. But how much can you get away with? I don't know.

Comment: Klumpy, So, suppose you don't care about getting down to 0 V at the output and don't want to create a negative rail to achieve it? Get some parts and build it and see where you are at. The Vds will be "something" above ground. You get to find out. The D1+D2 drops will be "something more." This will add to create an output voltage at Vin2. Meanwhile Vout1 will be 1.25 V above whatever Vds turns out to be. And the current limit will be the difference between Vds+2 diodes and Vds+1.25 V across Rsc. You get what you get.

Comment: Klumpy, You can use theory all day long and until the cows come home and still get nowhere because JFETs and 1N400x diodes aren't spec'd very well. And the 2nd one you build will be different from the first one. Now, if you create a weakly powered negative rail down around -10 V or maybe -15 V, then you start to get some consistency across builds because you are providing a wide margin to work with and closer to specs, too. But if you are shaving corners, then you get to see what those corners actually are and they will be different build to build.

Comment: Klumpy, If this is just a one-off build for hobbyist work, don't sweat the details. Just build one and see. You'll be fine with the results, I expect. If you really do want to be able to build something closer to a laboratory-like power supply, then you will need to think more about stuff, anyway, and likely provide some weak current compliance negative rails to get there. Or just buy one from someone. I used to build my own because I grew up poor and had to dig dumpsters for parts. But no longer. I buy. Easier, better, and I focus on other things.

Comment: That's quite helpful; I'm building a few of them for our school, but I wanted to figure out which corners I can cut to keep the cost down while still maintaining most of the functionality. I just wanted to know if most of those specs were important when finding JFETs online, but I guess I didn't make it clear in the question. I'm still learning how to write a good question, and the feedback has helped a lot. :)